# Scaling in "GraphicsGrid" command

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts

I want to plot four ellipses on the same graphics, along with some vectors and disks. I am using the `Graphics` command to create the arrows, ellipses and disks, and then the `GraphicsGrid` command to put the three figures together. The problem that I have is that they all appear with different scaling.

Here is a sample of my *Mathematica* code:

```
G0 = Graphics[{{Thick, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/10], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/10]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/10], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/10]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[v[Pi/10]], 
       Sqrt[v[Pi/10]]}]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.3], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2 - Pi/10, Pi/2 + Pi/10}]}}, Axes -> True, 
   Ticks -> None];
G1 = Graphics[{{Thick, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/4], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/4]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/4], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/4]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[v[Pi/4]], Sqrt[
       v[Pi/4]]}]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.3], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2 - Pi/4, Pi/2 + Pi/4}]}}, Axes -> True, 
   Ticks -> None];

GraphicsGrid[{{G0, G3}, {G1, G2}}]
```

where the code for `G2`, `G3` is identical to the one for `G0` (and `G1`), apart from replacing `Pi/10` with different angles, and `v[x]` is a function that returns a real number for each angle.

This is what my result looks like:

[image]

All arrows are of length 1 and so the vectors in all four graphics should be equal in a correct 1-1 scaling. I have tried using the option `"ContentSelectable -> False"` but it does not help.

Can anyone provide help on how to correct this? If necessary, I could drop the graphic on the top right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reproduces your plot,

```
v[x_] := x/3 // N
{theta, theta2} = {\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]};
G0 = Graphics[{{Thick, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/10], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/10]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/10], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/10]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[v[Pi/10]], 
       Sqrt[v[Pi/10]]}]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.3], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2 - Pi/10, Pi/2 + Pi/10}]}}, Axes -> True, 
   Ticks -> None];
G2 = Graphics[{{Thick, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/2 - theta], Sin[Pi/2 - theta]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-Cos[Pi/2 - theta], Sin[Pi/2 - theta]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[v[theta]], 
      Sqrt[v[theta]]}]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.3], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2 - theta, Pi/2 + theta}]}}, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> None]; G1 = 
 Graphics[{{Thick, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/4], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-Cos[Pi/2 - Pi/4], Sin[Pi/2 - Pi/4]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[v[Pi/4]], 
      Sqrt[v[Pi/4]]}]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.3], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2 - Pi/4, Pi/2 + Pi/4}]}}, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> None];
G3 = Graphics[{{Thick, 
      Arrow[{{0, 0}, {Cos[Pi/2 - theta2], Sin[Pi/2 - theta2]}}], 
      Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-Cos[Pi/2 - theta2], Sin[Pi/2 - theta2]}}], 
      Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Circle[{0, 0}, {1/Sqrt[v[theta2]], 
        Sqrt[v[theta2]]}]}, {Gray, Opacity[0.3], 
      Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2 - theta2, Pi/2 + theta2}]}}, Axes -> True,
     Ticks -> None];;
GraphicsGrid[{{G0, G3}, {G1, G2}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

The trouble is that when you defined each `Graphics` object, you let the system decide on the [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) value, which determines how big the arrow is relative to the plot.  You can fix this by giving each unit the same PlotRange,

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Map[Show[#, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}] &, {{G0, G3}, {G1, 
    G2}}, {2}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: My pleasure.  In the future, you should try to add all the code necessary to reproduce the problem.  I had to toy around with it and write my own copies of your graphics to do this.  That can discourage others from helping if it seems it will take too much effort  :-)

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. Thanks!